# Interact with other views while a popover is active

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, interactive, uipopover

I have a `toolBar` and I have setup two `UIBarButtonItem` on it. Both `UIBarButtonItem` are containing `UIButton`s as their `customView`s.

I activate a popover for their `Touch Up Inside` event as below,

```
    [popover1 presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:buttonItem1 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

I have another `UIButton` named **clearFilters** inside the main view. (Also this is the view which is containing the above `toolBar`.) I have declared a method for **clearFilters** button's `Touch Up Inside` event.

My problem is,
I can not interact with the **clearFilters** button while a `popover` is active. So, I'm looking for a solution to interact with this **clearFilters** button, while a `popover` is active.

I tried by adding `passthroughViews` property for a **popover** as below and it do not work as I expect.

```
popover1.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:clearFiltersButton];
```

What could be the reason. As the documentation has mentioned I can not see any issue.

I expect if the above things are correct, then the `Touch Up Inside` event of the the **clearFilters** button's should be fire up.

So, please show me if there is any issue or a necessary way to work on this thing.

I'm working on XCode4 and iOS 4.3.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried making the entire navigationBar passThrough?

Comment: I tried after you commented. But no result. The funny thing is while a popover is active, the other UIBarButtonItem responses to my taps whithout passthroughViews property. So, I need such behavior for other views which are outside the toolbar.

Answer (score 6):

The [UIPopoverController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) reveals why the other bar buttons can be tapped while the popover is visible:

**“When presenting the popover, this method adds the toolbar that owns the button to the popover’s list of passthrough views.”**

Try querying and logging the popover’s passthrough views. Does it already have things in it? Perhaps something like this would work?

```
myPopover.passthroughViews = [myPopover.passthroughViews arrayByAddingObject:clearFilters];
```

I haven’t tested this code, but it’s worth a try.